# Is there a way of rendering a widget conditionally without adding an else statement?

Tags: flutter

I want to render a child of a column only if a given condition is true.
I am only aware of doing this using the ternary operator.
My issue is that you have to specify an else block if the condition is not met. Does Flutter offer another way of conditional rendering similar to React's conditional rendering?

**React example**

```
{unreadMessages.length > 0 &&
    <h2>
      You have {unreadMessages.length} unread messages.
    </h2>
  }
```

**Flutter Issue**

```
Column(children: [
                  true ? Container() : Text('Hello'), // remove else block
                ],),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Column(children:[
if(unreadMessages.length > 0) Text('This will render only if length is > 0')
])
```